# Trying to parse JSON with PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

I'm new to php and this has really stumped me - i'm trying to parse this json in order to get the value of `match_id`.

```
{
    "result": {
        "status": 1,
        "num_results": 1,
        "total_results": 500,
        "results_remaining": 499,
        "matches": [
            {
                "match_id": 649218382,
                "match_seq_num": 588750904,
                "start_time": 1399560988,
                "lobby_type": 0,
                "players": [
                    {
                        "account_id": 4294967295,
                        "player_slot": 0,
                        "hero_id": 69
                    }
                ]

            }
        ]

    }
}
```

So far I have:

```
$matchhistoryjson = file_get_contents($apimatchhistoryurl);
$decodedmatchhistory = json_decode($matchhistoryjson, true);
$matchid = $decodedmatchhistory->{'match_id'};
```

But I'm pretty sure that's not the right way to do it at all. All I need out of this JSON file is the match id.

Comment: Why do you think that's not the way to do it?

Comment: Your json is not valid. You have a bad comma at the end of `players`

Comment: Because when I `echo $matchid` I get nothing.

Comment: @Brewal sorry that is a typo i've introduced - there are actually more than one players hence the comma, I just shortened it to make it more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an array back from `json_decode()` as you passed the second parameter with a value of `true` so you access it like any multi-dimensional 
array:

```
$matchhistoryjson = file_get_contents($apimatchhistoryurl);
$decodedmatchhistory = json_decode($matchhistoryjson, true);
echo $decodedmatchhistory['result']['matches'][0]['match_id'];
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/DWpQKv)

Naturally if you have multiple matches you wish to get the match ID for you can loop through `$decodedmatchhistory['result']['matches']` and get them accordingly.

Comment: There is also an extra comma in the JSON string, so in this case `json_decode()` will return NULL. (Edit: reading the [OP's comment here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23568834/trying-to-parse-json-with-php#comment36167328_23568834), it looks like a typo, so it doesn't matter) :)

Comment: Realized that myself as I set up the demo. As long as it is just a typo I feel ok posting this as answer.

Comment: That's got it cheers - I'm actually limiting it to one match result (the most recent). But I will bear in mind looping through if I need more than one result in the future. Thanks! Will mark as answer ASAP

Answer (score 0):

This is your code:

```
$matchhistoryjson = file_get_contents($apimatchhistoryurl);
$decodedmatchhistory = json_decode($matchhistoryjson, true);
$matchid = $decodedmatchhistory->{'match_id'};
```

Two issues. First when you set `true` in a call to [`json_decode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) that returns the results as an array:

```
When TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.
```

So you would access the data as an array like this:

```
$matchid = $decodedmatchhistory['match_id'];
```

But your original syntax is incorrect even if you were accessing the data as an object:

```
$matchid = $decodedmatchhistory->{'match_id'};
```

If you set `json_decode()` to `false` or even left that parameter out completely, you could do this instead:

```
$decodedmatchhistory = json_decode($matchhistoryjson);
$matchid = $decodedmatchhistory->match_id;
```

So try both out & see what happens.